# getorgchar - Customize the DetailsView?

Tags: detailsview, getorgchart

Is it possible to customize the DetailsView completely? Or can I specify my own template for it?

I've seen that it is possible to disable or enable it, but the out of the box DetailsView is not what we are looking for

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to customize the details view. You can use the following example as a starting point: http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Custom-Edit-Form